# Json2Apex implementation issue

Tags: apex, salesforce1-app, json

I have the Json string coming from DB field and I want that to be converted to Apex. I tried the below code but that only returns the first instance in json string.

```
 { 
 "firstname":"abc", 
 "Lastname": "xyz",  
 }, 
 { 
  "firstname":"abc1", 
  "Lastname": "xyz1",  
 }
```

Apex class that i am using is

```
public class JSON2Apex {

    public String firstname;
    public String Lastname;



    public static JSON2Apex parse(String json) {
        return (JSON2Apex) System.JSON.deserialize(json, JSON2Apex.class);
    }
}
```

And how i am calling is

```
JSON2Apex obj = JSON2Apex.parse(json);
```

And it returns only

```
JSON2Apex:[firstname= abc, Lastname=xyz]
```

Can anyone suggests where am i doing wrong.I know we need to create List to hold all items but not sure where and how.

Comment: your json is invalid, validate it using http://jsonlint.com/ if you have to pass an array enclose inside [ .. ]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because it's not properly formed JSON. You're missing the outer square brackets (`[]`) that indicate it's a *list*.

**Correct**

```
[
    {
        "firstName": "John",
        "lastName": "Doe"
    },
    {
        "firstName": "Jane",
        "lastName": "Doe"
    }
]
```

**Incorrect**

```
{
    "firstName": "John",
    "lastName": "Doe"
},
{
    "firstName": "Jane",
    "lastName": "Doe"
}
```

I don't think JSON2Apex will give you a correct class to serialize into when you just have a `List`. What you really want would be to deserialize into a `List<JSON2Apex>`.

```
public class JSON2Apex {
    public String firstname, lastname;
    public static List<JSON2Apex> parse(String json) {
        return (List<JSON2Apex>)System.JSON.deserialize(json, List<JSON2Apex>.class);
    }
}
```

Comment: I actually confirmed that. You need to have an outer parameter for it to parse into a list. I wonder if this is a bug?

Comment: @sfdcfox confirmed what? I think it's just a mistaken assumption that the payload will be in object form instead of array form. I would argue the "bug" is just over-reliance on tools without thinking critically about the output.

Answer (score 2):

You need to make your JSON an array:

```
 [{ 
 "firstname":"abc", 
 "Lastname": "xyz"  
 }, 
 { 
  "firstname":"abc1", 
  "Lastname": "xyz1"  
 }]
```

And then parse it as an array:

```
public static List<JSON2Apex> parseList(String json) {
    return (List<JSON2Apex>) System.JSON.deserialize(json, List<JSON2Apex>.class);
}
```

Note: It appears that even in array syntax, JSON2Apex doesn't "get it right", as it still produces the same code as what you've posted in your original question. This is one of those cases where you need to know enough about JSON to be able to figure out what went wrong.

Alternatively, given a choice of changing your JSON, you could write it as follows:

```
{ "records": [{ 
 "firstname":"abc", 
 "Lastname": "xyz"  
 },
 { 
 "firstname":"abc", 
 "Lastname": "xyz"  
 }
]}
```

Which produces the following JSON2Apex code:

```
//
// Generated by JSON2Apex http://json2apex.herokuapp.com/
//
public class JSON2Apex {

    public List<Records> records;

    public class Records {
        public String firstname;
        public String Lastname;
    }


    public static JSON2Apex parse(String json) {
        return (JSON2Apex) System.JSON.deserialize(json, JSON2Apex.class);
    }
}
```

Comment: ok let me quickly try that.If that helps in my case.

Comment: I used the same concept and it returned the the output as (JSON2Apex: [
  
       firtname=abc,
       Lastname=xyz
    ],
  JSON2Apex: [
    firtname=abc,
    Lastname=xyz
  
    ])                            Which i assigned to List<JSON2Apex>, when i try to access the same it gives me empty list.